# OpenGL (ES): Efficiently get vertex data from texture

Tags: graphics, opengl-es, gpu, gpgpu

I have an OpenGL texture that I generate through a couple of render passes in my FBO.
Now I want to use the texture as vertex data in a VBO and render stuff with it.
Since all data is GPU-sided, is there an efficient way to transfer (or re-interpret) texture data as vertex data in OpenGL?
Or do I have to go all the way through the CPU with

```
// ... generate texture on GPU.
glReadBuffer(..where the texture is..);
glReadPixels(..., mainMemoryBuffer);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ..., mainMemoryBuffer);
```

? Or is there another way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. After some more research it seems that PBOs (Pixel Buffer Objects) are the OpenGL feature which enable this:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, myVbo);
glReadPixels(..., 0);
```

Unfortunately it seems they are unavailable on OpenGL ES ([see this thread on GameDevelopment](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/29427/can-i-use-pbos-for-textures-in-ios)).